# Understanding the error log implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, error-logging

I found this way of error logging in one of the application.

**Where is it actually logging the error?**

Error log call

```
ErrorLog oLogError = new ErrorLog();
oLogError.ErrorInfo[3] = ex.Message;
oLogError.ErrorInfo[4] = ex.StackTrace;
oService.LogError(oLogError.ErrorInfo);
oService.Dispose();
```

Definitaion of oService.LogError();

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute
    ("http://tempuri.org/LogError", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",                     ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",                            Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,                 ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public void LogError(string[] errorInfo) {
        this.Invoke("LogError", new object[] {
                    errorInfo});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure What is your "LogError" string mean in `this.Invoke("LogError", new object[]` .It ideally should have been a method name and not a string.

[Correct definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx)

```
public Object Invoke(
    Delegate method,
    params Object[] args
)
```

You are basically capturing the error information on a array.And then its passed to Logerror method.The Method inturn calls the invoke method.

Invoke executes the method specified as a delegate(first parameter which should be method name) using the array of object passed as the second parameter `errorInfo`.And the execution happens on the thread that is owned by the control.

Comment: invoke cannot accept string as a first parameter.it has to be a method name.for e.g  this.Invoke(somemthod, new object[] {        errorInfo});

Comment: FYI - protected object[] Invoke(string methodName, object[] parameters);..so "LogError" is the method name here.

Comment: is this invoke your custom method?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
  this.Invoke("LogError", new object[] {
                        errorInfo});
```

New an object, this object receive your `errorInfo` and log the error.